# How to check if stored procedure is done without errors?

Tags: c#, sql-server, silverlight, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In a Silverlight app. when calling an SQL Server stored procedure from Entity Framework Domain Service class, how to get a feedback that stored procedure is performed without errors?

```
public void MySPmethod(string par1, string par2)
    {
        this.ObjectContext.MyStoredProc(par1, par2); 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an error occurs, you'll get an exception.

If you don't get an exception, you know that it worked.

Comment: So, should I just use Try..Catch construction?

Answer (score 1):

rem's response is true. add to that that you can return the @@Error from the stored procedure to check the error code in your application.